Android barcode scanning in background without any visible UI with ZXing library
I want to create an application which continuously keeps scanning qr codes in background, just like super market's qr scanner. I was able to achieve continuous scanning using ZXing library but here I have to show the camera preview in order to make scanning work. In my case I do not want that. Please help if at all it is possible or I am completely understanding wrong. I am new to android development, so any help would be appreciated.
I created service to scan qr code in background. But it is not working properly and Scanned barcode: log is never getting print.
package com.cloudchef.recipecreation.service;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeCallback;
import com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeResult;
import com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeView;
import com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.DefaultDecoderFactory;
import com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.camera.CameraSettings;

import java.util.Collections;

public class BarcodeScannerService extends Service {

    public static final String ACTION_SCAN = "com.cloudchef.recipecreation.service.ACTION_SCAN";
    public static final String EXTRA_BARCODE = "com.cloudchef.recipecreation.service.EXTRA_BARCODE";

    private BarcodeView barcodeView;
    private String lastText;

//    private BeepManager beepManager;

    private final BarcodeCallback callback = new BarcodeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void barcodeResult(BarcodeResult result) {
            Log.d("BarcodeScanner", "Scanned barcode: " + result.getText());
            if (result.getText() == null || result.getText().equals(lastText)) {
                return;
            }

            lastText = result.getText();
//            beepManager.playBeepSoundAndVibrate();
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_BARCODE, lastText);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        barcodeView = new BarcodeView(this);
        barcodeView.setDecoderFactory(new DefaultDecoderFactory(Collections.singletonList(BarcodeFormat.EAN_8)));
        CameraSettings cameraSettings = new CameraSettings();
        cameraSettings.setRequestedCameraId(1);
        barcodeView.setCameraSettings(cameraSettings);
        barcodeView.decodeContinuous(callback);
        barcodeView.resume();
        Log.d("Parth test", "Barcode scanner service started");
//        beepManager = new BeepManager(this);
//        beepManager.setVibrateEnabled(true);
//        beepManager.setBeepEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        barcodeView.stopDecoding();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}


Welcome to StackOverflow. Researching is advised before asking. See: How to Ask.  Do realize that running the camera in the background has privacy implications so you should have found Access Microphone / Camera in background in Android 11

What @MorrisonChang says is relevant if you want the camera to run even when your app isn't in the foreground. Is this what you are looking for or do you only need the camera scanning when your app is running in the foreground - just without an actual camera preview ui component to display its content?

@MorrisonChang my app is runing as kiosk mode in a table device. So, my camera needs to be running when my app is in foreground only. It's just that I want to run barcode scanning without an actual camera preview ui component to display its content.

When using a library please check open/closed issues for related tickets, see: https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/issues/77
